# Slow MongoDB start time when data is replicated to a new machine

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2, wiredtiger

We have a 3.2.13 Mongodb replica set with WiredTiger on AWS.

We are observing a strange behaviour: when stopping and starting the mongod service, the start time is about **10 minutes**, but when stopping the mongod service, then replicating the data disk to a new AWS instance, and restarting on that machine, the start time is about **2 hours**.

What may be the cause for this?

Comment: Have you checked mongod.log file? What it says during that startup? `tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @JJussi it doesn't show anything after printing 'options' and 'wiredtiger_open config'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the initial slowness is because the EBS volume (which is restored from snapshot) is being initialized during the service startup.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html